# HTML - Use internal css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am loading a third party HTML with CSS using JQuery load. This is loading in a div as a part of page. I want:

- Loaded CSS apply only to internal HTML not to external.
- External CSS won't apply to loaded HTML.

`JS`

```
$('#load-html').load('ThirdPartyHTMLURL');
```

`HTML`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <div>Hi</div>
    <div id="load-html"></div>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could take a look at the [shadow dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) that allows you to affect "internal css" to a dom element in JS.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you want the external CSS to only affect the external HTML, and the CSS in the loaded (internal) HTML to only affect the loaded HTML?

Comment: @Kei. Yes. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> External CSS won't apply to loaded HTML

CSS that applies to a document applies to the **whole** document.

If you add more HTML to the current document, then the document's stylesheet *will* apply to it.

> Loaded CSS apply only to internal HTML not to external

There was a proposal for a feature that would allow this, but [it is not supported in any practical sense](https://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped).

---

So there are two ways to achieve this:

- Write your CSS carefully so the rules in it apply only to the elements you want it to apply to
- Don't put the two sets of HTML in the same document (e.g. use an iframe)

Comment: I need interactive HTML. If I go for iframe, not able to do. I have a menu on loaded HTML that should override full page on open.

Comment: @Veera — Then go with the first option. Write the CSS carefully so when the two stylesheets are combined you get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for your answer. We are loading third party CSS, but not in our hands to edit/control. We are writing document CSS, but it's difficult to monitor both and write carefully. Bcz, as you know both are huge files.